# Perl - opening and reading .ppt/.pptx files?

Tags: perl

I want to open and read the text that is in the slides of a PowerPoint presentation.
How can i do that?
I know i might have to use `Win32:OLE`, but so far all of the code examples that i tried didn't work.

EDIT:
I only have this partial code which doesn't work:

```
$file = "C:\file.pptx";
my $powerpoint = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Powerpoint.Application');
my $document = $powerpoint->Presentations->Open($file);
my $slides = Win32::OLE::Enum->new($document->Slides );
print $slides;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Yeah i edited my post

Comment: What platform are you trying to run this code on? The code in your sample will only work on Windows systems with PowerPoint installed.

Comment: That's exactly what i have.

Comment: When you say it does not work, what error do you get? You also say partial code, can you post the full script?

Comment: @Gerry that's my full code, i just want to make a test. For the error i'm getting, look at the answer below.

Comment: @gambit20088 ok, let me see.

Answer (score 1):

I have a short example which demonstrates [extracting bullet lists](https://www.nu42.com/2010/09/extract-bullet-lists-from-powerpoint.html).

Your particular problem is due to the

```
$file = "C:\file.pptx";
```

On the right hand side, you have a double-quoted string which contains `\f`. `\f` represents [form feed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed). That is, the string contains `C`, `:`, <kbd>FF</kbd>, `i`, `l`, and `e`.

You can use `$file = "C:\\file.pptx"` to get the actual path to `file.pptx` in the root directory of drive `C:`.

Comment: Now i get an error saying:
`Can't call method "Presentations" on an undefined value at C:\program.pl line 13.` which in my code here is the third line.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this? also verify that the file is accessible? Try by putting the file inside of the same directory which the script is in and then ensure to point to it accordingly by removing the path. Also ensure that the powerpoint file is a valid powerpoint file and can be opened with your installation of Powerpoint

```
use Win32::OLE qw(in with);
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft PowerPoint';

my $powerpoint = Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Powerpoint.Application') or die "Unable to open";
my $document = $powerpoint->Presentations->Open({FileName=>'c:\\file.pptx', ReadOnly=>1});
...do stuff from here...
```